# Os packages do R devem ter um tag proprio?

Tags: debate, tags, perguntas

Fiquei me questionando se seria interessante colocar tag do package do R, uma vez que eles correspondem ao ambiente que o problema ocorreu, mas por ser um tag muito específico poderia torna-lo menos interessante.

Por exemplo:
[Nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/313715/como-lidar-com-m%C3%BAltiplas-aspas-no-r) que eu fiz, que erá sobre chamar uma query de PostgreSQL dentro de uma função do R, mas para realizar isso eu precisava instalar o package RPostgreSQL, então achei que esta dúvida seria pertinente a quem usasse package, então tagiei com [RPostgreSQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/rpostgresql/info), mas logo retiraram tal tag.

Comment: Dê exemplos....

Comment: Eu nao conheco R, mas normalmente há um lugar onde voce importa as bibliotecas que voce está a usar. Inclua na sua pergunta essas bibliotecas. Por exemplo no `java` isso seria feito com `import` no `node` seria feito com `require` e no `c#` seria feito com `using`. etc

Comment: Poderá também ser interessante incluir o nome da biblioteca no titulo da pergunta assim como no corpo da pergunta.

Comment: Creio eu que foi correta a retirada, pois o tal package não é a causa do problema, e provavelmente a questão das aspas vai ser enfrentada em qualquer outra situação em R, por se tratar da sintaxe nativa. Se quiser ajudar eventuais leitores sobre a necessidade do pacote, basta por no corpo da pergunta algo do tipo "Estou usando o _package_ RPostgreSQL, e estou com dificuldade quando preciso fazer _queries_ com múltiplas aspas" (algo assim). A tag faria sentido se fosse um problema específico do package.